# Get-AzApplicationInsights is not recognized

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-yaml-pipelines

I constructed a new Azure Pipeline and added this 'Azure CLI' task to try and run some Azure CLI Powershell scripting. Primarily, I want to do some checks on an existing AppInsights resources.
(Azure CLI)
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureCLIV2/Readme.md

I get this error when runnin 'Get-AzApplicationInsights' inside the Azure CLI Task.

```
'Get-AzApplicationInsights' : The term 'Get-AzApplicationInsights' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function.
```

The whole yaml script looks like this:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI Powershell'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ####
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     Write-Output "RESULTS:"
     az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
     Get-AzApplicationInsights -ResourceGroupName ############# -Name ############## Select-String -Pattern "PricingPlan"
```

Is there something I am missing as to why the cmdlet is not being recognised? Should there be a module I need to first to import?

Comment: Hi, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run the Azure powershell `Get-AzApplicationInsights`, just run it in the [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops).

Or if you want to use the Azure CLI task, you could use CLI command [`az monitor app-insights component show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/application-insights/monitor/app-insights/component?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_application_insights_az_monitor_app_insights_component_show) directly instead of the powershell command.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Joy Wang.

Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.applicationinsights/get-azapplicationinsights?view=azps-5.6.0#examples), `Get-AzApplicationInsights` is power shell CMD install or Azure CLI, we should run it via the task Azure Power Shell instead of Azure CLI task.

[image]

Build definition sample:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '{Subscription}'
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: 'Get-AzApplicationInsights -ResourceGroupName "{Resource Group Name}" -Name "{Application Insights name}" -IncludePricingPlan'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Result:

[image]